# Understanding WiFi routing and gateway

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, routing, raspberry-pi

**The solution** is explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/203109/115120)

**The problem**

I have 3 interfaces eth0, wlan0, wlan1 (2 wifi USB dongles) on my Raspberry Pi.

- wlan1 will be used to connect to a WiFi camera via SSDP.
- wlan0 will be used to have a TCP connection to a server (IP/domain name known). I know nothing about the WiFi wlan0 is connected to via DHCP. It could change from time to time. It doesn't know the gateway especially.
- eth0 will be used for debugging SSH access, via my MacBook Air connection sharing service by example.

Actually, all these interfaces are working. Here's the ifconfig output (wlan1 and eth0 are on the same network but that will not be the case in the future) :

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:8c:e2:10  
          inet addr:192.168.0.19  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1174 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:141 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:93616 (91.4 KiB)  TX bytes:12342 (12.0 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c0:4a:00:2a:ab:6c  
          inet addr:192.168.43.44  Bcast:192.168.43.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1142 (1.1 KiB)  TX bytes:1145 (1.1 KiB)

wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:da:38:0c:c6:f0  
          inet addr:192.168.0.14  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1480 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:155 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:222449 (217.2 KiB)  TX bytes:29711 (29.0 KiB)
```

And here's the output of sudo route -n :

```
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan1
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.43.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

If I understand well what I've read for the last 24 hours, I need to do routing stuff. But I don't understand what and how.
Did I have to change the default route? If yes, how can I manage to do that since I don't know the wlan0 or wlan1 gateway before connecting to the network?
Is that an impossible problem?

Edit : add /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
        post-up route del default dev wlan0

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
        wpa-ssid "wifi1"
        wpa-psk "psw1"

auto wlan1
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet dhcp
        wpa-ssid "wifi2"
        wpa-psk "pwd2"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've answered this question myself after hours of testing ...

It's explain [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/203109/115120)

Answer (score 0):

You can look at your file located at /etc/network/interfaces to find the default gateway.  It is probably 192.168.0.1, but I can't be sure.  The gateway is just your router's address.

Type "cat /etc/network/interfaces" to see the info.  Edit with root privileges (sudo) if you want to change it.

Try This:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    # post-up route del default dev wlan0
    address 192.168.0.19
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    wpa-ssid "wifi1"
    wpa-psk "psw1"
    address 192.168.43.44
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1

auto wlan1
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet static
    wpa-ssid "wifi2"
    wpa-psk "pwd2"
    address 192.168.0.14
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1
```

Backup your original /etc/network/interfaces file and try this one instead.  This sets everything to static(unchanging).  You will have to restart your interfaces with ifdown/ifup or just restart the computer.

Comment: Actually I've use this file to configure wlan0 and wlan1 and there is no gateway (dhcp config).

Comment: Ok, you can set the gateway.  Add "gateway 192.168.0.1"  or whatever address you want.  This is what mine looks like www.deanspicer.mooo.com/example.txt

Comment: Try to use your browser to navigate to 192.168.0.1.  If that goes to your router, then that is your gateway.

Answer (score 0):

> If I understand well what I've read for the last 24 hours, I need to do routing stuff.

Not unless you want to set up your system as a router.

The default gateway is the IP Linux will send traffic if the destination doesn't fall in the range of any network interface's subnet masks.  Typically this will be traffic destined for the "Internet."

If you don't care about this system having Internet access, you don't need one, but you probably do so it can get updates, etc.

DHCP typically hands out a default gateway as well as an IP address.  So if `wlan0` is getting an IP from DHCP it's probably getting a default gateway as well.  (Or it should be, may want to check your DHCP server if it's not handing one out.)  So Internet-destined traffic will go through that interface.

If you don't want to use DHCP or hand out a default gateway via DHCP you can specify it manually.  It should be the IP address of a router that can forward to/from the Internet.

Things will go smoothest if you only have one default gateway, so make sure your other interfaces are set to static IPs and that only one interface is getting something via DHCP.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've played with the dhcp client hook to set the `wlan0` default gateway. See my answer here : http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/203109/115120